# VB6 connectivity with oracle on windows 10

Tags: oracle, vb6, odbc

I have installed the vb6 and oracle 11 g client(instantclient_11_2) on windows 10.
I created one odbc connection and now trying to connect oracle db but its giving error while connecting the db using vb6 form.

> Error :"Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019"

I am using the connection string like :

```
sconnstring = "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER = servername;uid = user id;pwd= password}"
```

Comment: You try to use a 20 years old language and a 25 years old ODBC driver (both are deprecated for ages) on a current Windows? Change to current technologies then it will work. At least you should use to ODBC driver from Oracle rather then the Microsoft driver.

Comment: Did you set `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: What is the version of the Oracle Database Server?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit environment variable already set and oracle database server is Oracle 11 g , i installed oracle client (instantclient_v11)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the ODBC connection use ODBC 32 ...under windows\sysWow

Comment: Driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" exist only for 32-bit. Using 64-bit by accident is even not possible.

Comment: i am using 32 but only

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ODBC driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) for ages, you should not use it anymore.

Download and install the "ODBC Package" from [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows 32-bit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html), then it should work.

Comment: currently i am using instant client version 11 , It should also work,actually we tried this version 11 on windows 7 ,its working over there but now on windows 10 ,its giving above error.

Comment: You mix some points. The Microsoft(!) ODBC driver does not work with Oracle Client 11 in Windows 10. However, the Oracle ODBC driver 11 works also on Windows 10. Just a note, the Oracle InstandClient does not include the ODBC drivers by default. Some time ago we performed many tests but I don't remember each single result. At the end we ended by installing version 12.1 on our new Windows 10 machines in order to gain maximum compatibility for all our databases and applications.

Comment: i already installed version 12.1 oracle instant client and resolved the odbc connectivity,now i need to check vb codes again

Comment: @VimalSingh What does the connection string look like, particularly the driver portion?

Answer (score 0):

instant client for microsoft odbc is not available for Windows-10 operating system.
Then in that case for windows-10 we need to use Oracle ODBC client 12 version for odbc connection.Its working for me.